# Sum slices of consecutive values in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sum

Let's say I have a numpy array `a` containing 10 values. Just an example situation here, although I would like to repeat the same for an array with length 100.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I would like to sum the first 5 values followed by the second 5 values and so on and store them in a new empty list say `b`.

So `b` would contain `b = [15,40]`.

How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```
b = [sum(a[current: current+5]) for current in xrange(0, len(a), 5)]
```

It takes slices of 5 at a time from the list, sums them up and constructs a list. Also works for lists which aren't a multiple of 5 in length.

(`xrange` should be `range` in python3+)

Comment: this is not efficient. You should use Numpy API whenever possible when working with np.array, as seen in other answers here. I've just started learning how to work with Numpy so I may be mistaken but as a rule of thumb, if you're using `for` you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I would argue the **exact opposite**: You should use numpy (or efficiency constructs over general constructs) sparingly and only where you really need it. Efficiency is needed in very specific cases. Do not let them dictate your code.

Comment: It's true you shouldn't prematurely optimize your code, but this question was asked regarding a Numpy array. Given that context the answer should use Numpy API. What if someone just starting out using Numpy uses this answer but are doing image processing work? Performance would be very poor and so this answer would only waste their time instead of helping them.

Comment: "What if" is exactly the type of thinking that causes premature optimization. I still disagree about using library APIs for something readily available in the host language. What if this code needs to be used in more contexts? What if it needs to move to a different library? What if it is read and maintained by a dev not fluent in numpy? We can raise any assumption to support our claims but we only know what the OP asked. There is a simple solution in python that any python programmer can understand.

Comment: Numpy is so common in some domains that using native python constructs might be stylistically discouraged. In addition, in many cases where numpy arrays are already used, they are dealing with large arrays so the 20x speedup is worth it.

Answer (score 25):

One way is to use the `add` ufunc with its [`reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(a, [0,5])
array([15, 40])
```

This sums the slices `a[0:5]` and `a[5:]` and returns a new array.

If you want a Python list, you could call `tolist()` on the returned array.

You can use any list of indexes with the method (and they do not have to evenly spaced). For example, if you want slices of 5 each time on an array of length 100:

```
>>> b = np.arange(100)
>>> np.add.reduceat(b, range(0, 100, 5))
array([ 10,  35,  60,  85, 110, 135, 160, 185, 210, 235, 260, 285, 310,
   335, 360, 385, 410, 435, 460, 485])
```

Comment: But I would need the same for a larger array of len = 100 !! Is there a way to extend it ?

Comment: The method is very adaptable - can you clarify what you want for the larger array?

Comment: When I perform this for the larger array, I get only two values! but I need to get 20 values, as my array is of len = 100

Comment: @user3397243: I've added some additional info to my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Here's (yet) another solution:

```
In [3]: a.reshape((2,5)).sum(axis=1)
Out[3]: array([15, 40])
```

Reshape the one-dimensional array to two rows of 5 columns and sum over the columns:

```
In [4]: a.reshape((2,5))
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

The sum along each row (summing the column entries) is specified with `axis=1`. The reshape happens without copying data (and without modifying the original `a`) so it is efficient and fast.

Comment: could you elaborate further?

Comment: But for this I would need to change the shape for every new array !

Comment: Yup: if the arrays are not all the same length you'll need to calculate the correct shape to use here: e.g. the shape to resize to would be `(n//k, k)` for an array of length `n`  summed over consecutive chunks of length `k` and `n` had better be divisible by `k`.

Comment: I prefer this solution; no manual loops, and it is general for all (most?) Numpy functions (sum, mean, ...), which the solution with `reduceat` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
step = 5

for i in range(0,a.shape[0],step):
    print(np.sum(a[i:i+step]))
```

Comment: this is not efficient. You should use Numpy API when possible when working with np.array

Comment: @SagieLevy, the accepted answer does the same thing with list comprehension, might be worth commenting on that

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, calculating sums of **5** consecutive elements:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print(a.reshape((-1,5)).sum(axis=1))
```

In general, to perform a numpy array operation **oper** (for example `mean` or `max`) on **N** consecutive elements:

```
print(a.reshape((-1,N)).oper(axis=1))
```

Note that `len(a)` must be divisible by `N`.