# How to add two neighboring elements into a new one in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For example,
I have a numpy array containing:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to create an array as follows:

```
[3, 7, 11]
```

That is, I want to add the two neighboring elements into a new one.

I have tried the obvious:

```
for i in range(0, predictions.shape[0]+1, 2):
    new_pred = np.append(new_pred, (predictions[i] + predictions[i+1]) / 2)

print(predictions.shape)
(16000, 0)

print(new_pred.shape)
(87998, 0)
```

But the dimension of `new_pred` is not half of 16000.
So I am wondering is there anything wrong with my code? And is there a convenient way to implement it?

Comment: Also: [Sum slices of consecutive values in a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391815/sum-slices-of-consecutive-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slices of ndarray:

```
predictions[::2] + predictions[1::2]
```

It is 10 times faster than "reshape" solution

```
>>> a = np.arange(10**5)
>>> timeit(lambda: a.reshape(-1,2).sum(axis=-1), number=1000)
0.785971520585008
>>> timeit(lambda: a[::2]+a[1::2], number=1000)
0.07569492445327342
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many different possibilities, here it is one, neither the slowest one nor the fastest, of them,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(30)
>>> a.reshape(-1, 2).sum(axis=1)
array([ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57])
>>>
```

---

For the record (please note that we have a new [fastest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217199/2749397) that, imho, can't be bettered at all)

```
In [17]: a = np.arange(10**5)                                                             

In [18]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,2).sum(axis=1)                                              
1.08 ms ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit [(a[i]+ a[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(a-1), 2)]                          
23.4 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit [sum(item) for ind, item in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:])) if ind%2 == 0]      
49.9 ms ± 313 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit [sum(item) for item in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]                                  
30.2 ms ± 91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
...
In [23]: %timeit a[::2]+a[1::2]                                                           
78.9 µs ± 79.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

another pythonic Possibility would be to use list comprehensions: 
something like this for the example you posted:

```
  import numpy as np


  a = np.arange(1, 7)


  res = [(a[i]+ a[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(a-1), 2)]

  print(res)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip`

```
zip_ls = zip(ls[::2], ls[1::2])
new_ls = [sum(item) for item in zip_ls]
```